# How to exclude logging an Guzzle's 404 error in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use the Laravel framework. When I get an exception `GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException(code: 404)`, this event is added to laravel.log. How can I disable adding the event about that error to laravel.log?

Comment: I update question's title because Laravel already ignores some types of errors for you, such as exceptions resulting from 404 HTTP "not found" errors or 419 HTTP responses generated by invalid CSRF tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it from the exceptions handler file according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#ignoring-exceptions-by-type), if can be found in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` so for example:-

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException; // here, import the target class
...
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
/**
* A list of the exception types that are not reported.
*
* @var string[]
*/
protected $dontReport = [
        ClientException::class, // here, add the class to the don't report list
];

...
}
```

to manipulate a custom error condition, you can register it in the register method in the Handler file like:-

```php
**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // check if the ClientExeption is a 404
        $this->reportable(function (ClientException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == 404) {
                return false; // or anything else for that matter
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: But it will be removed for all statuses of the ClientException. I need to remove only the 404 status. Can I add a status code check somewhere?

Comment: i don't think so, but we can work around it by accessing the `getResponse()` method of the ClientException

Comment: @aleks_sk i update the answer try that

Comment: yes, this is what I need. Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: No problem buddy, happy coding.